# I'm using an expo application and don't know how to display this code: data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJe+/ve+/ve+/ve+/vQoxIDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9

Tags: react-native, expo

the code comes from this request:

const displayPdfFile = async(contract)=>{
axios.get(`${url}/files/${contract.id}`, {
headers: {
Authorization: await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
}
}).then(res=>{
const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
const fileReader = new FileReader()
fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
fileReader.onload = ()=>{
console.log(fileReader.result)
}
}).catch(e=>{
alert(e)
console.log(e)
})
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [rn-pdf-reader-js](https://github.com/xcarpentier/rn-pdf-reader-js) lib:

```
npx expo install rn-pdf-reader-js
```

```js
import PDFReader from 'rn-pdf-reader-js';

const base64 = 'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi...';

export const Draft = () => {
  return (
    <PDFReader
      source={{
        base64,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

[image]